# Show that a lower bound of a set need not be unique but the infimum a given set is unique

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I just want to see if my proof is verified. It seems pretty straightforward I combined two remarks from the book.

Proof: If a set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and is non-empty and has one lower bound then it has infinitely many. Let $M_0$ be a lower bound. Then so to is $M$ for any $M \lt M_0$. Therefore the lower bound a set is not unique.

However, if a set has one infimum then it has only one. Let $i_1$ and $i_2$ be infimums of the set $E$. Then by definition they are both lower bounds of the set and follows that $i_1 \leq i_2$ and $i_2 \leq i_1$ Therefore by the trichotomy property $i_1 = i_2$. So it is obvious that the infimum of a set is unique.

Comment: The last part needs more justification: $i_1$ and $i_2$ are both lower bounds so $i_1\leq i_2$ and $i_2\leq i_1$. As stated, this isn't quite correct (the conclusion is correct given $i_1$ and $i_2$ are infimums of the set $E$, but you must use the fact that each is an infimum and not just that they are lower bounds for the set).

Comment: I don't think you explained why $i_1\leq i_2$, since $i_1,i_2$ aren't necessarily in $E$. For your proof of the lower bound statement, what you have done is fine, but just as a technical note, you proved something stronger.

Comment: What did I accidently prove then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof for non-uniqueness  of lower bound is good.

For the uniqueness of the infimum you missed some important points.

You let $i_1$ and $i_2$ be infimum of the set $E$

Since $i_1$ is infimum of $E$ it is the greatest lower bound of $E$ therefore it is greater than or equal to $i_2$ which is a lower bound of $E$ that is $$i_1\ge i_2$$

Similarly we have $$i_2 \ge i_1$$

Thus $i_1 =i_2$ which proves the infimum is unique.

Comment: That does make more sense

Comment: Thanks for your attention.